# VLC window STUCK on top of display and CANNOT BE MOVED - Any ideas?

Tags: vlc-media-player, lubuntu

This is what I am up against. I just installed the new version of Lubuntu and VLC is stuck in this position with the top bar hidden out of the display.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try to reset the vlc-settings by using the command: `rm -rf ~/.config/vlc`

Answer (score 6):

Same happened to me in Raspbian. I discovered all you have to do is hold the Alt key, left click and hold on the VLC window and drag it where you want it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I reset my settings like @Stackcraft_noob. This brought my window in the center. The only work-a-round I have found is going to Preferences > Openbox configuration manager and clicking on the margins section and setting a top margin of 25px. It always moves to the top but never hides the menu bar.